# In quitcktime when screen recording is Save the same as Export to 4K?

Tags: quicktime, youtube, 4k, screen-recording

In order to prepare videos for online sites for courses and youtube, I do fullscreen recording on my mac book pro with the default resolution of:
1440 x 900

I then export as 4k. However, when I do 'Save as' instead, the filesize is the same as the 4k one. So my question is:

Is **Save** the same as **Export to 4k**?

I am using Quicktime 10.5

Comment: Could you double-check that figure… 1440 x 900 ?

Comment: @Tetsujin on my mac I have Resolution set to 'Default for display'. When I check Scaled on the Default option it says 'Looks like 1440 x 900'

Comment: I'm still wondering why you are wanting to upscale the video. You will gain no more detail at 4k, merely make 4 times as much data to be transmitted & decoded.

Comment: @Tetsujin thank you. But when I do 'Save' instead of export the filesize is the same as 'Export to 4k'. Would you suggest Exporting to something like: 1080p?

Comment: Presumably Save is saving at 1440x900. 1080p would also be an upscale. I can only guess that your attempt to upscale to 4k is not saving what you think it is. Try grabbing a freeware media info app from the app store so you can actually see what is happening to the files.

Comment: @Tetsujin good idea. Will do.